PHP :: create file name with emoji characters using fopen
I'm trying to create file name without text and use emoji instead.
If I'm putting the character itself it is working perfectly
BUT
I want to use safer method inside my php code so I replaced it with the hexadecimal value.
so this is working perfectly:
$myfile=fopen('','a');

but this is not (...it does creating a file but not with the expected emoji)
$myfile=fopen('&#x1f464;','a');

I'm quite sure it is extremely simple only the correct syntax is needed here))

You need double quotes to enable interpolation. But HTML won't work here, use UTF instead. Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double $myfile = fopen("\u{1F464}", 'a');

Damn! I was using it long time ago in some of my scripts but I completely forgot about it :)) Problem Solved! Thank You!

Relevant: How to convert code hex to associated character in php and Unicode character in PHP string

Thanks to @Markus Zeller
I found a solution based on HIS comment :)
$myFile=fopen(mb_chr('128100','UTF-8'),'a');

or:
$myFile=fopen("\u{1F464}",'a');

Thank You! 
